# Push a new version notification for a "one page" site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am working on a application written with ROR and backbone, it's basically a 1 page application that uses ROR as a api and with the help Backbone and js templates renders all the UI.

When I deploy a new version we have users that don't refresh the browser tab, I will like to determine that a new version was deployed and push a notification to them asking to refresh the page.

What will be a good way to determine from the client that a new version was deployed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably make a `/version` route that will return SHA of currently deployed git revision. The client can periodically fetch this url and see if it's changed.

This approach lets server not worry about maintaining list of currently connected clients (for  push notifications). And more importantly, it's simple to implement.

Comment: pooling the server sure should simpler, but it's a waste of bandwidth I will prefer to push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without the need to poll the server:

The client should send its version with each APi call to the server (can be an HTTP Header)

If the server supports the client's version, it will succeed and return the desired data.

Otherwise, the server will return an error code specifying that the client is no longer supported. The UI can then show a message asking to reload the page.

In backbone terms, you'll need to override the "sync" method of the Models, or configure the transport layer (default is jQuery to add the HTTP headers to every AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I also like using browser push Simple: http://pusher.com/ for this... so you could:

Pivotal Tracker does this:

- Push a notification to users that they should save their work 15 minutes before a change
- Push a notification to users that the app needs to refresh

Comment: this is all manual, done by an admin or a server side script right?